# I'm having a hard time getting a jquery trigger event to fire. I have a webpage using an jquery ajax call using to call a form on another php file

Tags: ajax, events, dynamic, triggers

I'm having a hard time getting a jquery trigger event to fire when it the page is being loaded via ajax.  I have a webpage using an jquery ajax call using to call a form on another php file

```
$('#orderFormPlace').load('orderForm.php');
```

On this PHP page, there is a change event attached to form objects with the class "checkMe"

These form objects are populated dynamically so this is what I have set up for this

```
$( "table" ).delegate( ".checkMe", "change", function( e )
```

What I need to get working is this following code to trigger the event:

```
$("[id=vendor1]";).val($("[id=vendor1]").val()).focus().trigger("change");
```

The mystery is... it works when I have it on the same script it does exactly what I want it too, but when it's being called by an AJAX call (jquery .load function) it doesn't want to work.

Why doesn't it work when I have it loading via AJAX?

I found this and it claims there is a workaround, but there is no demo or example that it claims to have.  Something about using javascript document.getElementByID and usting jquery .index().  I tried fiddling with it but I don't see how .index() can be used as a selector with the javascript getElementByID.

Now what I want to know is... what sorcery is this!?!?

Many Thanks ahead for your time.

---

edit: I solved my problem by hardcoding the code instead of trying to trigger a change to do the same thing.  But the question still remains as to why it's happening.

Comment: Syntax error: Unexpected token `;`, you have a rouge `;` in you code.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're generating javascript code in `orderForm.php`, which you want executed when the Ajax request is executed.

I find it much easier to seperate markup and scripts - so let the file `orderForm.php` only deliver the necessary markup, and then, from your main script, attach event handlers to the (newly loaded) elements.

If you use Ajax to load some more elements, you might end up with a situation where the old elements got event handlers attached and the new ones don't. Either you clear all of them out and re-assign them to each element, or use [jQuery's live() function](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or, best, consider assigning the event handler only to a parent element and check via event.target which element was originally adressed, reducing the number of total event handlers greatly ("event delegation").

Also, I've got questions regarding the provided code snippets:

```
$("[id=vendor1]";).val($("[id=vendor1]").val()).focus().trigger("change");
```

Let's get rid of the `;` and replace `id=` by `#`:

```
$("#vendor1").val( $("#vendor1").val() ).focus().trigger("change");
```

Why are you setting the value of `val` to the value of `val`?

Comment: Sorry, it should be vendor 2, the values are actually dynamically changed, but for simplicity sake, I just hardcoded the number.  it should be something like:
    $("#vendor1").val( $("#vendor2").val() ).focus().trigger("change");

Comment: Thank you for your response!  I'm fiddling with it as you have spurred me to think of some other solutions using live and on.  I believe live is deprecated so I'm looking at using .on --

I'm not sure how to execute your suggestion about the event.target.  Is that more for efficiency?

Comment: Maybe [http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) can help you. Also, I love using `on` and `off` combined with ["namespaced" event names](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events).